# Description of class followed by list

Tags: grammar

I am not certain whether I correctly write a sentence in which I first state something and subsequently inform the reader more about that statement (in an academic paper). For example:

1. Spectacles consist of two components, the frame and the glasses.
2. Emma has two types of shoes, trainers and heels.

Are these sentences correct? Should I add 'namely' after the comma or replace the comma by a colon?

Comment: My spectacles ("glasses") have five components: the frame, two side arms, and two **lenses**.

Comment: I forgot two hinges and two nose pads, so mine have nine components.

Comment: On one of my pairs, the side arms are themselves two-component widgets. Each has the metal arm itself, plus a plastic ear-protecting sleeve over the end. And I think you'll find that the hinges have *three* components: the piece in the front frame, the piece in the side arm, and the screw used to join them. And depending on type, the nose pads might also have two components: pad, and screw. So that takes the component count up to as much as, what, SEVENTEEN?

Answer (score 1):

The sentences would be understood as they are by most native speakers, but strictly speaking they could be seen as ambiguous. That's because it's not absolutely clear from the structure that the comma is separating the name of a list -- "two components", and "two types of shoes" -- from that list's components. That is as opposed to it separating the first and second components of an unnamed list. It's easier seen with your second sentence. Is it saying:

> A) Emma has three things: 1) two types of shoes, 2) trainers, and 3) heels.

or is it rather:

> B) Emma has two things (which happen to be types of shoes): 1) trainers, and 2) heels.

As I say, context would lead most people to the correct conclusion that the intended meaning is B). And that goes for your first example as well. In each case the first thing mentioned is a *class* of things -- "components", "types of shoes" -- and the remaining things can be viewed as *members* of that class. Fair enough. But that fact -- i.e. in the above example, the fact that the intent is B) and not A) -- is not clear from the *structure* of the sentence. And it's not hard to come up with sentences where the context does *not* help in resolving the structural ambiguity. Here's an example:

> John has three homes, a yurt in Oregon, a hunting lodge in Texas and a converted mountain bothy in the Scottish highlands.

From that alone, we cannot tell if John owns three properties or six. We cannot tell unless we also know if John regards yurts, hunting lodges, and converted bothies as "homes". (And even if we knew he did, we still couldn't be certain that he saw that specific yurt, lodge, and bothy as *the* three homes mentioned at the start.)

Now you could clarify things using "namely" as you suggest (or even the latin [*viz.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viz.)) But it would be simpler, and I think easier for the reader, to simply fix the comma, which is the root of the problem.

So, back to your sentences. Were I writing them, I would replace the comma in each with a full colon. I tend to use a full colon, and not a semi-colon, as my list *initiator* because although it doesn't apply to your examples, if any of the individual list items were sufficiently long and complex that they needed commas *within* the item, then I'd want the semi-colon to be available as my list item *separator*.

Finally, even though I am a Brit, when writing lists I've come to appreciate the extra precision offered by the so-called [Oxford comma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma). So I'd write your two examples as:

1. Spectacles consist of two components: the frame, and the glasses.
2. Emma has two types of shoes: trainers, and heels.

And here's an expanded version of my own example, using everything I've mentioned above. That is: a colon as list *initiator*; semi-colons as list *separators*; and an Oxford "comma" (although here it is really an Oxford *semi-colon*) to explicitly separate the second-last and last items on the list.

> John has three homes: a yurt in Oregon; a hunting lodge, supposedly once owned by the Kennedys, in Texas; and a converted mountain bothy, small but cosy, which is great after a day in the mist and rain, in the Scottish Highlands.

Answer (score 0):

They are good sentences.
You don't need *namely*.
*Namely* could be used in a more complex sentence as a separator.
A colon would have a formal, official feeling, at odds with referring to Emma by her first name.